# Networking on WindowsPhone8 while app is suspending

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am facing a problem with network communication when a Windows Phone 8 app is suspending. The expected behavior is when, the app goes in suspended state (via pressing the back button or my other ways), a logout needs to be performed, using a new StreamSocket.

Basically what seems to happen is that StreamSocket's ConnectAsync method seems not to terminate (hangs).
When the app resumes from suspended state, the ConnectAsync terminates, and the logout is performed.

Are there any well-known limitations using sockets on Suspending event?

Any hints/suggestions how this scenario could be achieved?

Comment: Problem solved, it was not what I suspected. One of the async chains were not awaited.

Comment: Answer your on question,some-other will have benefit from this